# Rooted Phone: Apps have root permission

Tags: android

I'm developing an app that (I believe) needs root privilege.  There are plenty of instructions on the web for rooting a phone.  My questions is:

If I root my phone, do all apps get root privelege automatically, e.g. a File Manager or ADB?

(I'm familiar with root privelege on desktops, but Android is a different animal).

A previous answer from "Ali" said to "acesss [the app] in SuperUser".  I'm not sure what that means.  Do I have to mod my app? Do I launch it differently? or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes If you access File Manager or ADB in Super User.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but what does it mean to "access ... in Super User".  Do I have to do something special in my App?

Comment: Well when you root your phone , you get SuperUser app that mange your apps permission and you should allow them to access to the root.

Comment: Without superuser, each app which needs root permission will ask you with a popup window. You can allow the app for that "run" or allow it forever.

Answer (score 0):

even you root your phone.the applications do not have root pemission excepts doing something

special.